# d3js skip data if position is negative

Tags: d3.js, brush, rescale

here is part of code.

```
    function transition_data() {
        svg.selectAll(".bar") 
        .transition()
        .duration(500)
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.startDate) })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.index) })
        .attr("height", function(d) { return 20; })
    }
```

through brush, bar graph is re-scaled. but some y(d.inex) data is - or over height. 
how to skip or remove them?

I tried to add

```
.data(data.filter(function(d) { return  y(d.index) > 0 && y(d.index) < height  }))
```

it cannot hide out of brush section bars whose y position is - or over height..

Comment: My guess would be that you're only applying the filtering function to the data that is selected by the brush. Try applying it to all of the elements in your dataset. e.g. `points.filter(function (d) {...});`

Comment: if already drew once, old chart bars which not filtered are not hide. I moved old chart bars that should not be displayed to somewhere not in my svg. (-10000 or 100000 some like this)